# ASP.NET Web API conflict after installing VS 2012 Ultimate

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2012

I installed asp.net mvc-4 beta a while ago to host our api. It worked fine until I just installed vs2012 ultimate on my machine. The project is neither compiling in vs2010 nor in vs2012. What can I do to resolve this conflict. Furthermore, I bin deployed asp.net web api assemblies on my server. What I have to do to run the latest build (once the previous problem is solved) on server?

**Edit:**
The compilation errors when I open in vs2012 are

```
'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage' does not contain a definition for 'GetUserPrincipal' and no extension method 'GetUserPrincipal'...

'System.Web.Http.Hosting.HttpPropertyKeys' does not contain a definition for 'UserPrincipalKey'
```

In vs 2010 on the other hand, it refuses to accept types like DelegatingHandler and others. Some errors are as follows.

```
The type or namespace name 'DelegatingHandler' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The type or namespace name 'HttpResponseMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

I have installed the latest build of asp.net mvc 4 as well and the version its showing me is 4.0.20713.0. Previously, I added web-api beta using nuget. I have removed them all and installed latest builds of web-api from nuget.  I don't know what could be the problem. One thing, I don't understand: why do I need to install web-api assemblies seprately when they are supposedly part of mvc framework?
thanks

Comment: The compiler errors would be useful. And to update your web api bins just use nuget and replace your current bins with the RTM release or nightly builds.

Comment: First error is the type or namespace `FormatterContext` cannot be found. Same is the case with `HttpRepsonseMessage` and `HttpRequestMessage`

Comment: I'm not having compile issues with mine, but Intellisense keeps highlighting it saying it doesn't exist.  Not sure what's up with it.

Answer (score 0):

Add using System.ServiceModel.Channels; to your file. The Extension methods for HttpRequestMessage exist in this namespace according to [THIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.httprequestmessageextensionmethods.getuserprincipal.aspx).

Comment: By putting backticks around the `using System.ServiceModel.Channels;` you can mark code fragments as such.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
using System.Net.Http;
```

You probably have the reference already, so just add the using for the extension method.
Otherwise add the Assembly of the same name.